# What is the ID/password when a folder is shared using "Sharing Options" of Caja?

Tags: 20.04, samba, ubuntu-mate, caja

Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS. I installed the `caja-share` extension and installed `samba` (but not manually configured anything). In Caja, I right-clicked a directory, chose "Sharing Options", and checked "Share this folder" and "Allow others to create/delete files...". I clicked "Create Share".

Now, on another Linux system (Gnome), I opened the Files (Nautilus) and clicked Other Locations, and then typed the name of the server "smb://serveraddress". It showed two directories, one was the directory I just shared and another was "print$". I tried to open the shared directory, and it asked me for the ID/password. I entered the same ID/password that I use to log on the Ubuntu Mate server, but it just showed the dialogue again with empty input fields.

What id/password am I supposed to enter? Does Caja not setup such ID/password and do I have to manually setup Samba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to open the shared directory, and it asked me for the
> ID/password. I entered the same ID/password that I use to log on the
> Ubuntu Mate server, but it just showed the dialogue again with empty
> input fields.

You need to add your Linux server user to the samba password database.

So if I wanted to add myself I would issue on the server a:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a morbius
```

Comment: That worked, but it is kind of thoughtless that the Caja's GUI does not automatically do this or at least tell the user that he needs to do this. I mean, on Windows, just sharing the directory in File Explorer's GUI is enough; a grandma would not have to open command prompt and type this kind of command to share directory. But on Linux, a lot of app developers seem to expect users to know all these command-line arguments to to basic tasks like sharing a directory.